# How can I prove that this function is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ ($n\geq 2$) a bounded domain. Let $u \in L^{1}(\Omega)$.
Let $F(x,k):= \chi_{\{ u> k\}}(x), (x,k) \in \Omega \times (-\infty , + \infty) $.

I am trying to show directly by definition that the function $F$ is measurable.
For a real number $a<0$ we have

$$\{ (x,k) \in \Omega \times (- \infty,+\infty) F(x,k);  > a\} = \Omega\times( \infty,+\infty) $$

For a real number $a\geq1$ we have

$$\{ (x,k) \in \Omega \times (- \infty,+\infty) ;F(x,k)  > a\} = \emptyset $$

I dont know how to write the set

$$\{ (x,k) \in \Omega \times (- \infty,+\infty); F(x,k)  > a\} ,$$

in the case $a \in [0,1).$ Someone could help me?

I just know that in this last case we have

$$\{ (x,k) \in \Omega \times (- \infty,+\infty); F(x,k)  > a\} = \{ (x,k) \in \Omega \times (- \infty,+\infty); u(x) > k\} ,$$

thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if one real number is greater than another, there exists a rational between them.

So for each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, consider the set
$$A_q = \{ (x,k) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R} : u(x) > q > k \}.$$
Show that $A_q = u^{-1}((q, \infty)) \times (-\infty, q)$ and hence $A_q$ is measurable.

Now show that $\{(x,k) : F(x,k) > a\} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} A_q$.